# Converting Array of type float to doubles

Tags: c++, arrays

I really need help on learning how to convert arrays of different types to doubles (short, long, float). I'm not really sure how to ask the question any better. This is for an assignment for school. I understand that the assignment isn't complete, I just need to learn to do this before I continue to make arrays for short and long types.

```
Assignment Description:
```

We are going to expand program to account for different primitives. This implementation will implement all 8 functions described in program 2 as templates. To show this works, the main function will declare 4 different arrays that contain 10 values. The different arrays will be declared as shorts, longs, floats, and doubles. Each array will be filled with random values from a random-number generator. The array will be printed, then each of the 8 functions will be called and the results printed to the user. In order to provide a container, each of the functions will be part of a class called “MathHelper” that has all of the functions declared with a public access modifier and a static modifier.

MathHelper.h

```
#pragma once
class MathHelper
{
  public:
    static double calculateSum(const double numbers[], const int& count);
    static double calculateAverage(const double numbers[], const int& count);
    static int highestNum(const double numbers[], const int& count);
    //int lowestNum(const int numbers[], const int& count);
    //int numRange(const int numbers[], const int& count);
    //double standardDeviation(const int numbers[], const int& count);
    //int smallestFactorial(const int numbers[], const int& count);
};
```

MathHelper.cpp

```
#include "MathHelper.h"



MathHelper::MathHelper()
{
}

double MathHelper::calculateSum(const double numbers[], const int& count)
{
     if (count <= 0)
        return 0;
     double total = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         total += numbers[i];
     return total;
}

double MathHelper::calculateAverage(const double numbers[], const int& count)
{
     if (count <= 0)
         return 0;
     return static_cast<double>(calculateSum(numbers, count)) / count;
}

int MathHelper::highestNum(const double numbers[], const int& count)
{
     if (count <= 0)
        return 0;
     int highest = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
        if (highest < numbers[i])
             highest = numbers[i];
    return highest;
}


MathHelper::~MathHelper()
{
}
```

Program4.cpp

```
// Program4Fix.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathHelper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    double* myDoubles = new double[size];
    float* myFloats = new double[size];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));


    // double fill
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Double Array: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(myDoubles + i) = rand() / double(RAND_MAX)*50.f + 1.f;
        std::cout << i << ": " << std::setprecision(4) << *(myDoubles + i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << "The sum of the numbers is: " << MathHelper::calculateSum(myDoubles, size) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << "The average of the numbers is: " << MathHelper::calculateAverage(myDoubles, size) << "\n";


    // long fill
    std::cout << "Float Array: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(myFloats + i) = rand() / float(RAND_MAX)*50.f + 1.f;
        std::cout << i << ": " << std::setprecision(4) << *(myFloats + i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << "The sum of the numbers is: " << MathHelper::calculateSum(myFloats, size) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << "The average of the numbers is: " << MathHelper::calculateAverage(myFloats, size) << "\n";




    return 0;
}
```

---

I guess my real question is, is there anyway to use a value of type double* to initialize an entity of type float*?

```
const int size = 10;
double* myDoubles = new double[size]; // this works
float* myFloats = new double[size]; // this doesn't work, is there a way to do this similar to the one above?
```

Comment: Well, you need to figure out how to ask a better question. There's nothing much to converting some numerical type to another. C++ does it for you automatically. If `i` is an `int`, i.e. `int i;`, then to convert it to a double you just ...do it: `double d=i;`. That's it. But that's obviously not your question, so you need to figure out exactly what you're asking. Dumping pages of irrelevant code is not going to clarify that.

Comment: I think template might help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about C++, don't use implicit conversion

```
double d = 1.5;
int i = d;
```

Also don't use c-style casting:

```
double d = 1.5;
int i = (int)d;
```

Make use of proper casting

```
int i = static_cast<int>(d);
```

You can read up on why, there are many reasons why to cast in C++.

For converting the array, you need to create a new array and then iterate over the existing one, convert one by one and then assign them to the new one.

For C++11 you can possibly use the std::transform() function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you should do is generalize the functions in MathHelper to template functions which can be used for other types than `double`. I would get a decent C++ book and read about template functions, e.g. in [A Tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html) or [Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html). You can get the first four chapters for the Tour of C++ from [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/tour), and the second chapter introduces templates.

In the end, you should have code that looks like

```
class MathHelper
{
  public:
    template<typename T> static double calculateSum(const T numbers[], const int& count);
};
```

As a general remark, the posted code looks very C-ish meaning that it uses C-constructs where C++ has better alternatives, e.g. manually managed arrays instead of `std::vector`. You should avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

Converting to double from `float`, `int`, or `long` is as simple as just assigning the source variable to a variable declared `double`.

For example:

```
int a = 1
long b = 2;
float c = 3.0f;
double result;

result = a;
result = b;
result = c;
```

In the 3 last statements, the values will be converted to doubles for you.

You can also convert the other way by casting.

```
const int size = 10;
double* myDoubles = new double[size];
float* myFloats = new float[size];
InitializeArray(myDoubles); // You'll have to start with some values
for(int i = 0; size > i; ++i)
{
  myFloats[i] = (float) myDoubles[i];
}
```

Comment: @DaneWind In the example above, `InitializeArray()` is whatever you want it to be, just to give your doubles some initial values.